# Display two different buttons in a page based on the objects in a JSON response

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, boolean-logic

In my angular app, I have an array called "cart" which can be empty or have some objects.I am trying to display Refer button in my page whenever the array is empty.When the array has any objects, it should display the Buy button though.In my case, when the array is not empty,it can have  maximum of two objects- Now and Later or any one based on the scenarios.

I am trying something like this but in both the cases Refer button is being displayed.

My html-

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
     <button *ngIf="clickToRefer">Buy</button>      
     <button *ngIf="!clickToRefer">Refer</button>     
 </div>
```

In my .ts file-

```
 if (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.result.cart.length; i++) {
        var obj = data.result.cart[i];
        if ((obj !== undefined) &&
            (data.result.cart.length > 0) &&
            ((obj.option == 'Now') || (obj.option == 'Later'))) {
            this.clickToRefer = true;
        } else {
            this.clickToRefer = false;
        }
    }        
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
}
```

inside export i have declared-

```
clickToRefer : boolean;
```

Here , data has the entire response which has cart array.I am getting the response properly.

Can someone help me knowing where I am going wrong.

Comment: Why are u checking data.result.cart.length again inside the if condition ?

Comment: To ensure the array is not empty.Without that it was not able to check properly whether the array is empty or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just a JS logic issue, not angular.

Inside of the for loop "obj" can't be undefined and the length of the array will always be > 0 so your sample of code is the same as:

```
 if (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.result.cart.length; i++) {
        var obj = data.result.cart[i];
        if ((obj.option == 'Now') || (obj.option == 'Later')) {
            this.clickToRefer = true;
        } else {
            this.clickToRefer = false;
        }
    }        
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
}
```

I suspect that your data.option is never 'Now' or 'Later'?

Comment: Exactly my point. Why would it enter the loop in the first place if the length = 0 in the OPs qs

Comment: Though checking for undefined may be required i suppose.

Comment: I don't think so because the i will always be between 0 and the length of the array - 1, so data.result.cart[i] will always have data. JS doesn't allow undefined items in an array. 
I think the check should be for obj to be an Object.

Comment: I was doing the same way before but this was not checking properly so I have added that.

Comment: @remib yes, its failing when cart is an empty array.

Comment: You need to check if data.result.cart is defined before the loop.